# Could not find or load main class org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2CPP

Tags: c++, wsdl, wso2

I am newbie to web service and WSDL. I am using WSO2 to create my first web service.
For that matter, I am using Calculator.wsdl which is provided with WSO2 binary version.

I executed below commands to generate service skeleton:
    `WSDL2CPP.bat -uri Calculator.wsdl -ss -sd -d adb -u` (with Axis Data Binding)
and
    `WSDL2CPP.bat -uri Calculator.wsdl -ss -sd -d none` (with no data Binding),

I got output as:
Could not find or load main class org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2CPP

I am using WSO2 version 2.1.0 on Windows.
I have added follwing to PATH variable as well, 
    D:\wso2-wsf-cpp-bin-2.1.0-win32\lib;
    D:\wso2-wsf-cpp-bin-2.1.0-win32\bin\tools\codegen\wsdl2cpp;

I know this is very basic question but I am stuck on the very first step.

Could you suggest any pointers in this regard.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I am stuck on this. can anybody share some thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

You may not have set the required environment variables, such as `WSFCPP_HOME`. Please ensure that you have completed all steps in the WSO2 WSF for C++ installation instructions[1].

For your reference, the WSO2 WSF for C++ product documentation is located at [2].

[1] http://wso2.org/project/wsf/cpp/2.0.0/docs/install_guide_windows.html

[2] http://wso2.org/project/wsf/cpp/documentationhttp://wso2.org/project/wsf/cpp/documentation

Answer (score 0):

More specifically (in addition to Gokul's answer), you need to go through the process of installing Maven, downloading the codegen tool and building it.  This is described very briefly in the links given by Gokul.

I don't think your problem is environment variables, but rather that you didn't go through the process of building the codegen tool.